# Jersey ExceptionMapper, rely on another ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jersey, exceptionmapper

I have an `ExceptionMapper` which is part of a generic common library:

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<GenericException> {
    ...
}
```

Now, in my specific project, I have my own `ExceptionMapper`:

```
@Provider
public class SomeAdHocExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SomeAdHocException> {
    ...
}
```

I would like to convert the `SomeAdHocException` to `GenericException` and let `GenericExceptionMapper` be responsible for further processing. I tried the following two options, but both are not working:

[1] throw `GenericException` in `SomeAdHocExceptionMapper`:

```
@Provider
public class SomeAdHocExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SomeAdHocException> {
    public Response toResponse(SomeAdHocException e) {
        throw new GenericException(e);
    }
}
```

[2] inject `GenericExceptionMapper` into `SomeAdHocExceptionMapper`:

```
@Provider
public class SomeAdHocExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SomeAdHocException> {
    @Inject
    private GenericExceptionMapper mapper;

    public Response toResponse(SomeAdHocException e) {
        return mapper.toResponse(new GenericException(e));
    }
}
```

Both options are giving dependency excpetions.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt won't work because only *one* exception mapper can be called for a single request. This is a safety feature to ensure that we don't run into infinite loops. Imagine `XExceptionMapper` throws a `YException` during processing and `YExceptionMapper` throws a `XException` during processing.

Your second attempt won't work because the mapper isn't injectable. You *could* just instantiate it though.

```
@Provider
public class SomeAdHocExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SomeAdHocException> {

    private final GenericExceptionMapper mapper = new GenericExceptionMapper();

    public Response toResponse(SomeAdHocException e) {
        return mapper.toResponse(new GenericException(e));
    }
}
```

Assuming there is such a constructor and that the generic mapper doesn't require any injections of it's own. If it does, you *could* make the mapper injectable.

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindAsContract(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to inject it.